# Multiple views over a single Kendo data source

Tags: kendo-ui

Using the Kendo DataSource am I able to create more than one view over a single data source.
To take a simple example say I had a list of people in the dataSource and I wanted to bind this data source to two list views, one list sorted ascending and one sorted descending, is that possible.

In a view/modal API one would expect the view to be separate from the model precisely so one could have multiple views over a single model. With Kendo it appears to be a one to one relationship. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple controls share a DataSource, as seen on the [Shared DataSource](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/datasource/shared-datasource.html) demo page.

I also recall hearing of one DataSource wrapping another DataSource, allowing the two to sort differently. I can't find a link for this right now though.